# How to merge branch to master on bitbucket

Tags: branch, bitbucket, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I have following questions.

1. I want to create a `branch` from my `master` **repo**. I can use either `bitbucket dashboard` or `Terminal` to create a branch. If I used `Terminal`, the created branch does not show in `Overview`.but if I used `Create a branch` from dashboard and create, it shows the branch but din't contains anything and asked me to do checkout with `git fetch && git checkout branchname` command.
   Which one is the correct way to create a branch?
2. Then my next question is , Think my `master` has **Changed** and my **Branch** is also chanaged. so how can I merge my **branch** changes to **master**. what are the steps to do that. (Best way is to use commands or the bitbucket dashboard merge)
3. Finally , if we typed `git branch`, it shows `master` and `other branches`. so how can I change the branch from terminal.

Answer (score 12):

1) When you create a branch on Bitbucket, that branch does not exist locally.  This is probably why the dashboard is recommending that you do `git fetch`.  Git fetch will bring the newly created branch into your local Git.  After this, you can do a checkout via `git checkout newBranch`.  Had you created the branch locally, the steps would have happened in reverse.  Specifically, the new branch would exist in your local Git, but would not exist on the Bitbucket remote until you did a `git push`.

In my experience, creating a branch locally via `git checkout -b` is the typical way to create a branch, as usually this is being done by a developer in his local environment.

2) To merge your branch's changes to `master` you can try the following:

```
git checkout master
git merge yourBranch
```

Keep in mind that it you follow Bitbucket's workflow, the merge might actually be happening as part of a pull request.

3) To switch branches locally, just use `git checkout <branch_name>`.  For example, to switch to `yourBranch` from `master` you would type:

```
git checkout yourBranch
```

Comment: okay, if use terminal to create branch, how we can change Read, write permission. because I created a branch using terminal. when I try to push like `git push remote master`, it always says `Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.`. why is this.

Comment: This sounds like maybe you are not pointing to the right repository.

Comment: pretty sure I'm in the correct repository. what is the point of  `Please make sure you have the correct access rights` how this  part can be happen.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done by using:

1. checkout to master branch and
2. git merge your branch.

You will find the complete guide [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging).

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new branch from master: `git checkout -b newbranch`. You may need to push to make the branch available on the remote (git bucket)- `git push remote master`. I would do this when working on a project. Terminal would be preferable, otherwise you would 'pigeon hole' yourself into working with a specific UI, rather than a consistent CLI.
2. Make sure your master is upto date, by commiting and pushing any changes and then merge the other branch to master. Again, I would use Terminal.
3. `git checkout otherbranch` would change from any branch to `otherbranch`. Note that the `-b` flag is not passed in. This will just change the active `branch`.

Comment: okay, if use terminal to create branch, how we can change Read, write permission. because I created a branch using terminal. when I try to push like `git push remote master`, it always says `Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.`. why is this.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a remote branch with the same name as you used on your local repository.
with this branch available on the remote repository

You can now do git push